# command line in C#

Tags: c#, command-line, console

I have a tool which I want to run from my command prompt.

The code is as

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        string User;            
        if (args[0].Length  != 0)
        {
             User = args[0];
        }
        else
        {
        Console.Write("Please Enter the Username");
        User = Console.ReadLine();
        }
```

If I didnt give the username or the first argument after my 'tool.exe' in command prompt, it throws an exception like "Index was outside the bounds of the array"

I want ouptut as, if I didnt give argument - it should prompt me to give the username. please help me out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`args` is an array, and is what you should be checking for length. When you check `args[0].Length` you're actually assuming there's atleast one element in the array already and thus you're checking `Length` of the first item.

Try

```
if (args.Length != 0)
```

instead, which checks the length of the array of command line parameters.

Answer (score 2):

You don't want to call `Length` on the item.

```
            \/ Change here
     if (args.Length  != 0)
    {
         User = args[0];
    }
    else
    {
    Console.Write("Please Enter the Username");
    User = Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the if to:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{

    string User;            
    if (args.Length  != 0) // Change from args[0] to args
    {
         User = args[0];
    }
    else
    {
    Console.Write("Please Enter the Username");
    User = Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

After this call make sure you do a 
`string.IsNullOrEmpty(User)`
 beforen you use it.

Comment: Why the need to check for null or empty? Considering `args.Length` will only evaluate to larger than 0 if it's actually NOT null and NOT empty, what's the need for the extra check?

Comment: If it is then he does the Console.Readline();  thats why i say this.

Comment: Ah - after his `Console.ReadLine()`. Right. Wasn't entirely clear. =)

Answer (score 1):

do this

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{

string User;            
if (args.Length > 0)
{
     User = args[0];
}
else
{
Console.Write("Please Enter the Username");
User = Console.ReadLine();
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to check length of argument array, i.e. the number of arguments. Currently you are checking the size of args[0].

```
if (args.Length  != 0)
{
  // command have some params
}
else
{
 // command have no params
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just replace the following line:

> if (args[0].Length  != 0)

With the following code:

```
if(arg.Length !=0) <br>
```

In your code, you have referenced item 0 in the args array and then check its length. 
Since you want to check the array length, use the Length property of the array itselft

Answer (score 0):

By doing like this you are looking on the first element in the collection string[].

```
if (args[0].Length  != 0)
```

This will give a exception if there isn't any arguments.
Correct statement are the following if you want to check if there is any arguments.

```
if (args.Length  != 0)
//Or this
if (args.Any())
```

Observe that the Any() is a part of the namespace System.Linq.